# i am learning to deploying django project on pythonanywhere.com. What should i write to create virtual envirnment (mkvirtualenv --python=python3.??)

Tags: django, pythonanywhere

(djangoenv) C:\Users\GAGAN\Desktop\area_pro3>python --version
Python 3.7.5

20:45 ~ $ mkvirtualenv --python=python3.7.5 djangoenv
The path python3.7.5 (from --python=python3.7.5) does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Linux machine so use the Linux directories:

```sh
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.7.5 djangoenv
```

Comment: 20:37 ~ $ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.7.5 djangoenv
The path /usr/bin/python3.7.5 (from --python=/usr/bin/python3.7.5) does not exist

Comment: sir, i may have to type 3.8 or 3.7 ??

Comment: seems like python 3.7.5 is not supported on pythonanywhere but when i tried python3.7 and 3.8 it works. @GaganGrover you can use 3.8  with `mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 djangoenv` since it's the latest version

Comment: mkvirtualenv is actually pretty smart, and works out the interpreter's location for you -- so `mkvirtualenv --python=python3.7 djangoenv` on its own will automatically search for a Python 3.7 install on the system path, and then use that.